# Why the sequence of matrix transformations in The Annotated Transformer?

Tags: attention

Forgive me the long introduction, but I want to be very specific with my question.

[The Annotated Transformer](https://nlp.seas.harvard.edu/2018/04/03/attention.html) implements the Transformer architecture from "[Attention Is All You Need](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762)". The `MultiHeadedAttention` class implements the multi-headed attention mechanism with what, to me, look like tricks to simplify the code and improve performance. Specifically, the parallel application of multiple attention heads is implemented by handling all heads in the same matrix, one for each step of the attention computation.

My question is related to this line:

```
query, key, value = \
            [l(x).view(nbatches, -1, self.h, self.d_k).transpose(1, 2)
             for l, x in zip(self.linears, (query, key, value))]
```

It consists of:

1. applying a linear layer `l` to the input `x`
2. transforming the output to a 4D Tensor with dimensions describing, respectively: batch, attention head, word in the phrase, projection dimension

The question is: why does it have to be a combination of `view()` and `transpose()` rather than just a single call to `view()`? I could implement that line as follows:

```
query, key, value = \
            [l(x).view(nbatches, self.h, -1, self.d_k)
             for l, x in zip(self.linears, (query, key, value))]
```

It produces the output of the same shape and I checked that it works (at least on a CPU; I don't know about CUDA).

So why is it done this way? What is its advantage?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is technical: `view` can only operate on contiguous tensors and is supposed to be faster, `transpose` works for both contiguous and non-contiguous tensors.

There is a [blog post](https://jdhao.github.io/2019/07/10/pytorch_view_reshape_transpose_permute/) that tries to explain that, for a better understanding of what contiguous tensor means, there is a nice [PyTorch forum answer](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/contigious-vs-non-contigious-tensor/30107/2).

Comment: While these are good facts to know about `view` and `transpose`, they do not address OP's question, which is about how to compute multi-head attention in a transformer. Specifically, applying `view(nbatches, self.h, -1, self.d_k)` splits tensors along the sequence dimension, which is incorrect. The desired result is to split on the embedding dimension.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is not technical. You apply the `transpose` because you **need** to transpose the axes of the tensors.

Your input $x$ has shape $B \times T \times D$. Once you forward through the linear layer `l` you get the query embeddings which have the same shape. What you want to do is split this tensor along the last dimension, because this is where the embedding dimension is. That is why you **have to do** `l(x).view(B, T, n_h, D//n_h)`. After that you transpose axes 1 and 2 to get the desired shape.

If you apply `l(x).view(B, n_h, T, D//n_h)` you split the tensor along the wrong dimension - the sequence length dimension. Components of the embeddings of different tokens will get mixed up. You get the correct shape, but the wrong numbers.